# Plural of "computer bus"

Tags: plural-forms, spelling

I often see the word "bus" (in the sense of interconnect layer of a computer system) to be written in plural as either "buses" or "busses". Which one is the correct form?

Wikipedia uses both on the same [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_bus).

Comment: Because "bus" and "buss" have distinct meanings, it would be a source of confusion to use "busses" as the plural of "bus." Of course, context would eliminate confusion in the huge majority of cases, but I recommend "buses" for the plural of "bus."

Comment: I work in IT and have always written “buses.” A buss, to me, is a [kiss](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/buss).

Comment: Bus, used in both senses, comes from 'omnibus'.

Comment: I can't see busses used as a spelling on that page

Answer (score 1):

The plural of "bus" is generally "buses".

It appears the wikipedia article you mention was modified on the same day to correct this misspelling.

A number of different articles discuss the topic:

[Grammarly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/busses-buses/): "The plural form of bus is buses. To be fair, a few dictionaries do list busses as an alternative plural form of bus. But it appears so rarely that most people would view it as a spelling error."

[Mirriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/plural-of-bus): "The plural of bus is buses. A variant plural, busses, is also given in the dictionary, but has become so rare that it seems like an error to many people. ... Until 1961, 'busses' was the preferred plural of 'bus' in Merriam-Webster dictionaries. But the word 'buss' is a synonym of 'kiss'. Perhaps it's just as well that 'buses' took over."

[wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/busses): Lists both alternatives, and then states - "Buses (suffixing -es) is now the usual plural of bus in both British and American English."